# How can I redirect a user to the login page using angularjs and laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am working on a project using laravel and angularjs. I am using only Laravel to authenticate the users and when their logged in, then angularjs ui veiw will handle the navigation. when doing this I realized a problem, when the session has expire the user should be redirected to the logged in page based on the auth filter that is set on the route. Additionally when I checked the browser dev tool network tab, I see that the sign in page is send as a response. I am wondering how can I make my project redirect the user to the logged in page when the session has expire. how can I solve this problem and Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Comment: Instead of using standard synchronous authentication, take a look into asynchronous JWT authentication for AngularJs single page applications. So here are some resources to get you started. [JSON web tokens](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-introduction/), [example](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/05/json-web-tokens-examples/), [further reading on JWT](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/), and a laravel specific JWT package [tappleby/laravel-auth-token](https://github.com/tappleby/laravel-auth-token).

Comment: Just a note, and don't quote me on this, I believe for single page applications, asynchronous JWT authentication is the best path to take for single page applications. If anyone reading this knows otherwise please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect the user client-side in JavaScript use `location`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

For this case I think you want to look at `location.assign()` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with $httpInterceptor, here is demo code:

```
var myApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
myApp.config(function ($httpProvider, $provide) {
    $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $location) {
        return {
            'response': function (response) {
                //you can handle you sucess response here.
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                console.log(rejection);
                //if(rejection.data.xxx==="xxx")
                if(rejection.status === 408){//session expired code
                    alert('logout!');
                    // clear your local data here...
                    $location.url("/login")
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
myApp.controller("MainController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.response = {};
    $scope.triggerGet = function () {
        $http.get("/my/json").success(function (data) {
            $scope.response = data;
        });
    };
});
```

When your server side response is session expired, you can handle the `response.status` or you can handle the other data with `response.data`.

[Here is $httpInterceptor document.(In the middle of the page)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: going to try this out